# {% url %} not work in Django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, internationalization, django-templates

I have a problem using the tag `{% url%}` in Django on GAE, I found the problem applying internationalization in JavaScript files, writing:
`{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}`

Django throws the error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at / view / test /
>
> Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: Error Importing data
>   store piston.gae_store OAuth: "No module named piston.gae_store"

And try other parameters: `{% url prueba.views.prueba %}`

I get the same error.

If I remove piston throws another error on another package, and if only the URL url.py let me test the latter throws error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'

The final url.py:

> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       url(r'^view/', include('website.urls')), )

I hope I can help or show another way to get the url of the JavaScript I want without using `{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}`

Answer (score 0):

There is an earlier error that you did not yet fix:

> Error Importing data store piston.gae_store OAuth: "**No module named piston.gae_store**"

This does not seem to be related to the lines that you change. It will probably even occur when your remove the `{% url ...%}` completely, right? Try to fix the existing error first.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Anony-Mousse for the reply, yes the error is that had patterns url urls.py files that do not have a valid view, I deleted all the lines and I no longer throws that exception.

Comment: Buts the /jsi18n/ resulting from {% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %} does not work returning a 404.        
This is what I have in the url.py the project:  
js_info_dict = {'domain': 'djangojs','packages': ('conf',),}  
urlpatterns + = patterns ('', url(r'^jsi18n/$','django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog' js_info_dict))  
Where conf is the package that I have the settings.py file and the folder was created locale for translations

Answer (score 0):

Ready, everything was a rookie mistake in the localization work with Django, I'm so ashamed. Well first of all some the url patterns in the url.py files had not a valid view, second in the url.py project file I have a rule:

```
url(r'^(?P<nick>(\w)+)/$','app.views.tal_cosa')
```

And down:

```
url(r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog, js_info_dict)
```

So django try to find "jsi18n" as a nick (as in the first rule).

I climbed the jsi18n and ready. Thanks for everything

And sorry for my english I use google translator